# How to Access the data in XLSX sheet, where some fields are referred to another sheets?

Tags: python, pandas, xlrd

[image]

18F-AV-1451-A07 Value refer to another sheet called "CONTENT" in which column "B" and row "3".

I have load the dataframe using code

```
pd.read_excel('data/A07.xls',sheet_name = 'DM',skiprows = 12, skipfooter = 2)
```

[image]

I'm getting null value in that column of "Conversion Definition" instead of "18F-AV-1451-A07".

how can i get that data in my dataframe, and i don't want to do hardcoded.

Comment: Can you upload a sample dataset so that we don't have to create a sample dataset on our own and we can be certain our solution works.

Comment: First I would suggest you to delete your email id, second there is no way around this, you will have to write a custom function, as of now there is no way to make a dataframe aware of multiple sheets and make dynamic linking between them, Sorry :(

Comment: Hey have a look at this, I think this is what you are looking for https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1nF691qrDq9NIRrZvBKyCfZ4YV694TJfF

Answer (score 0):

First Credits, I didn't actually solve this, i took help from user U9-Forwrad, Now to do this you need

```
import pandas as pd
xlsx = pd.ExcelFile('Sample.xlsx')
df1 = pd.read_excel(xlsx, 'CONTENT', header=None)
df2 = pd.read_excel(xlsx, 'Sheet2')
boolean = df2['Class'].isin(df1[0].fillna(df1[1]).dropna())
idxs = boolean.index[boolean == True]
print(df2.iloc[idxs[0]:idxs[1]+1])
```

Which gives you

```
         Day Month Class
1    tuesday   Feb    CM
2  Wednesday   Mar   NaN
3   Thursday   Apr   NaN
4     Friday   May   NaN
5   Saturday   Jun   NaN
6     Sunday   Jul    DM
```

Which I think is what you are looking for.

Note: You will need to convert the file to xlsx, ODS format isn't supported by pandas.